# Javascript: how to obtain the tags of getSelection along multiple tags?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I wonder how to obtain the element tags of selected text along multiple tags.

For example,

```
<div>
  <p>I am (selection start)a boy</p>
  <p>You are a girl</p>
  <p>We are(selection end) friends</p>
</div>
```

When I print out `selection.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.tagName`, it shows "DIV".

However, I would like to obtain "p", "p", "p" for "a boy", "You are a girl", "We are", respectively.

Is it possible in Chrome browser? If it is, please help me!

Thank you for your time:)

Comment: there are other properties of the range you can use to flush out the extent, which you can use to slice the container's _children_ collection. the other thing you could do is clone it into a fragment and inventory that.

Comment: `[].map.call(getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents().children,x=>x.tagName)`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question but with query selector you can do something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll(“div > p”)
```

That will return all the “p” inside the div